# Horizontal inflection point of a cubic polynomial.

Tags: calculus

I could prove the "if" part of the following question. But I am stuck at the "only if" part.
The question is:

> Show that a cubic polynomial has a horizontal inflection point (where the slope is zero) if and only if it can be expressed in the form $(x-a)^3+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

The first part was proved by taking $f(x)=(x-a)^3+b$ and proving that it has a horizontal inflection point.

How do I prove that if it has horizontal inflection point, then the cubic polynomial is of the form $(x-a)^3+b$?

If I take the general cubic polynomial as $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, and using only the two conditions $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$ how can I get the values of $a, b, c$ and $d$?
Or, is there any other method ?

Comment: Well, $f(x)=2x^3$ would be a counterexample ...

Answer (score 0):

If, for some $x_0$, you have $f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=0$, then, if you write $f(x)$ as$$a(x-x_0)^3+b(x-x_0)^2+c(x-x_0)+d,$$then $b=c=0$, since $b=\frac{f''(x_0)}2$ and $c=f'(x_0)$. So, in fact, $f(x)=a(x-x_0)^3+d$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=a(x-b)^3+c$ it's easy to show that $f$ has in inflection point at $x=b$ with horizontal tangent.

Let $f(x)=a_3x^3a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=a_3(x^3+b'x^2+c'x)+a_0$. From $f''(x)=0$ we get $x=-b'/3$.  As $3x^2+2b'x+c'=0$ we find $c'=b'^2/3$.  Substituting in $f$ gives
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=a_3(x^3+b'x^2+b'^2x)+a_0\\
&=a_3\left(x^3+b'x^2+\frac{b'^2}{3}x\right)+a_0\\
&=a\left(x^3+b'x^2+\frac{b'^2}{3}x+\frac{b'^3}{9}\right)-a\frac{b'^3}{9}+a_0\\
&=a_0\left(x+\frac{b'}{3}\right)^3-a\frac{b'^3}{27}+a_0\\
&=a_3\left(x+\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)^3-\frac{a_2^3}{27a_3^2}+a_0.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, letting $a:=a_3$,$b:=-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}$ and $c=-\frac{a_2^3}{27a_3^2}+a_0$ we arrive in
$$f(x)=a(x-b)^3+c.$$

Comment: I misunderstood the question. The question meant that $f(x)$ is of the form $(x-a)^3+b$ and not equal to it.

Comment: I do not understand.  The claim: "A polynomial $f$ of degree $3$ has an infection point with horizontal tangent iff there exist $a$ and $b$ such that  $f(x)=(x-a)^3+b$." is false, consider $f(x)=2x^3$.

Comment: Doesn't $f(x)=2x^3$ have a horizontal tangent at $x=0$?; the X-axis itself.

Comment: Surely, but is it of the form $(x-a)^3+b$?!

Comment: Okay, I see your point. I think the claim should be modified to  $f(x)=a(x-b)^3+c$.